# Why can't I declare structure 2nd time in function?

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors, declaration

So, I got a function where I am declaring one structure which is filled and also want to declare one new function. When I declare new function on the top it works, when I declare it on the same line after comma (,) it works but it doesn't work on the bottom line. Any explanations? Thanks in advance.

```
void CFilter(float avgprofit, int lines)
{
    //client goodclient[MAX_CLIENT]; THIS WOULD COMPILE
    client client[MAX_CLIENT], goodclient[MAX_CLIENT]; // THIS COMPILES
    //client goodclient[MAX_CLIENT]; THIS WOULDN'T COMPILE
    int i, amount = 0;
    float userprofit;
    for (i = 0; i <= lines; i++) {
        userprofit = client[i].loses - client[i].wins;
        if (userprofit >= avgprofit) {
            client[i].goodclient = 1;
        } else {
            client[i].goodclient = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you have `goodclient` on the next line, did you remove it from the previous line? It is unclear. BTW please avoid using the same name for a variable as its type. At best: confusion, at worst: errors.

Comment: *Why can't I declare structure 2nd time in function?* Because you can't. It is actually a *definition* which cannot be duplicated. However a duplicate *declaration* such as a function prototype or external variable, can be - as long as they are all identical.

Comment: Good idea to start types with a capital letter - can then tell them apart from variables

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the name of the array `client` hides the name of the type `client`.

```
client client[MAX_CLIENT];
client goodclient[MAX_CLIENT];
```

So in the second declaration the compiler considers the name `client` as the name of the array.

It is not a good idea to use the same name for different entities.

The simplest way to make the compiler to compile the declarations is to rename the array.

Or if the type `client` is a `typedef` of a structure type with the same name then you can write for example

```
client client[MAX_CLIENT];
struct client goodclient[MAX_CLIENT];
```

Another way is just to exchange the declarations

```
client goodclient[MAX_CLIENT]; 
client client[MAX_CLIENT];
```